# Not able to delete a file from galaxy s

Tags: android

In my app I has to took a video and post it to a server. After that I has to delete that video file. I used `file.delete();`

That worked fine for all devices except in Galaxy S. I also tested in milestone, defy, and nexus s. In Galaxy S the video is still present in the media gallery, but when I checked using file.exists() it returned false.

When I tried to play that file again an alert is shown saying "Video format not supported". Any other way to delete the video file? Why this thing happens only in Galaxy S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your file itself is gone, but the media gallery is doing some aggressive caching of some preview/thumbnail, so that you see it there, but can not play it - as the underlying file is gone.